# Invalid column name 'Genre_Id1'. In Entity FrameWork

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I am newbie to Entity Framework Code First approach.
I was created the following Genre model:

```
 public class Genre
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

then add migration and update database.
After that I create The following Movie Model

```
 public class Movie
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public int NumberInstock { get; set; }

    public Genre Genre { get; set; }  

}
```

then add migration and update the database which generate a 'Genre_Id' column as a foreign key.

I try to add the following property to the MovieModel

```
 public byte Genre_Id { get; set; }
```

but when I run the application I got the error Invalid column name 'Genre_Id1'.
I don't have a column name like this.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is when I added a  Genre navigation property to MovieModel I should add  GenreId property also the add migration and update-database. That means add the navigation property and the property together then add migration and update database